# Change edge color in preview panel

Tags: gephi, graph-visualization

I am plotting a graph in Gephi. I used an edge attribute (negative and positive correlation) in the overview panel; it was good.

But the overview panel does not give me an as visually appealing image like the preview panel. However, the preview panel does not have the function of changing the edge color according to my attribute. Does anybody know how to change that?

In addition, sometimes the preview panel refreshes forever and has no result. Moreover, the figure in overview panel is small; when I zoom-in the text becomes vague.

Answer (score 1):

> … the preview panel does not have the function of changing the attribute for edge to color my edge according to my attribute. Does anybody know how to change that?

Edge coloring in `Preview` tab can be adjusted via:

`Preview` > `Preview Settings` > `Settings` > `Edges` > `Color`

Following options are available:

1. **Original**
   <sub>Colors edges according to color(s) set in `Overview` tab.</sub>
2. Mixed
   <sub>Colors edges by fading source- and target node's color.</sub>
3. Source
   <sub>Colors edges according to edge's source node color.</sub>
4. Target
   <sub>Colors edges according to edge's target node color.</sub>
5. Custom
   <sub>Colors edges according to a single selectable color.</sub>

> … sometimes the preview panel refreshes forever and has no result.

[Update Java](https://www.java.com/getjava), or position view to include all nodes:

`Preview` > `Preview` > `Reset zoom`

Disable display of a percentage of the graph (in case rendering takes too long):

`Preview` > `Preview Settings` > `Settings` > `Preview ratio`

Comment: Thank You! The preview panel color were solved. I donloaded a version earlier and the refresh also works.